# problems with reinstalling windows vista

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-vista

I want to dual boot (windows vista and Ubuntu) and i only have Ubuntu now, i also have an installation CD for windows vista, which i can start through PlayOnLinux.

My problem is that it says the following during the installation:
this computer does not have enough space available for temporary files. there is at least 449MB of free space on this partition necessary. Make space and start the installation again if you want to install windows.

error: 0x80004005

So the question is: where/how can i delete temporary files or how can i delete Ubuntu, so i can make windows my primary operating system.

with a little help i can also use the terminal, but rather not.

the total free space in my file system is 134,7GB

Comment: How much free space do you have on each of your partitions?

Comment: @Ramhound does not matter. He wants something answered related to WINDOWS. So this is offtopic. To answer the problem: you -must- install Windows on the FIRST partition of a disc. If that is in use you need to re-install ALL operating systems.

Comment: @Rinzwind - It might not be on topic here, that does not mean, its not on topic on another Stack Exchange website.  The migration of this question will be seamless on my end. My only goal is to answer his question but require additional information.

Comment: just tell me what more you want to know and then i will give it

Comment: @Rinzwind that is another problem, because i don't know how to re-install Ubuntu and get it on the second partition, but that would also solve my problem (i think).

Comment: If you want to install Vista as a dual boot, you **should not start the CD through PlayOnLinux.** Vista cannot be installed that way.

Comment: there is nothing important on my Ubuntu right now, so another solution is first installing windows and then Ubuntu (again), but the problem is that i don't know how to delete Ubuntu. I still have the Ubuntu installation disc, so that's no problem.

Comment: Simply boot off the Windows CD. You should be able to select your boot device in BIOS or EFI. You cannot install Windows by using PlayOnLinux.

Comment: @Jochem. Installing Windows will delete Ubuntu.

Comment: @TanelMae Mae I know, but i still have the Ubuntu install CD, now i just choose install ubuntu besides windows and the problem is solved.

Comment: @soulsource thanks i forgot that i could boot the CD in BIOS. If you post your comment, then i wil check it as the correct/good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply boot off the Windows CD. You should be able to select your boot device in BIOS or EFI. You cannot install Windows by using PlayOnLinux.

Although it is possible to install Windows after Ubuntu and get dual boot working (search askubuntu, there are probably guides for this), if you don't loose to much, I'd recommend to first install Windows and Ubuntu afterwards. During Windows installation, I'd leave some HDD space unpartitioned for later use with Ubuntu.